# networkx: 'super' object has no attribute 'node'

Tags: python, inheritance, superclass, networkx

I try extend a class from networkx.DiGraph

```
import networkx as nx
class branch(nx.DiGraph):
    def __init__(self,g,raiz):
        self.b=super(branch,self)
        self.b.__init__(g)
        self.r = raiz
    def strong(self):
        print self.b.nodes(),self.b.node[self.r]
        if self.b.node[self.r]['w']>0:                                                                                  
            return 1
        else:
            return 0
```

If I execute I get

```
[1, 'r']
...
AttributeError: 'super' object has no attribute 'node'
```

I can use `.nodes()` but no `.node[]` , why ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply enough, because `node[]` doesn't exist. Instead, `nodes()` returns an array that you can index with `[]`. The code for this might look something like `self.b.nodes()[self.r]`.

Comment: This is true, but doesn't fix the OP's misunderstanding of OOP. No reason to use `super` here at all: `self.nodes()` would work just as well.

Comment: @DanielRoseman , thanks you comment about self.nodes() I understand more

Comment: @DanielRoseman , and with `self.node[self.r]` I solved the problem, you can put you comment as answer ?